# flutter doctor not working in my MacBook Air console

Tags: flutter, dart

```
Error: The Flutter directory is not a clone of the GitHub project.
       The flutter tool requires Git in order to operate properly;
       to install Flutter, see the instructions at:
       https://flutter.dev/get-started
```

I have installed it properly and Git is also installed and Xcode also installed which flutter is also working and `export PATH="$PATH:/Users/siddiq/flutter/bin"` path also has been set properly and path also showing properly.

Comment: In the same console window, try typing `git --version` - what do you get? I assume Git is installed but not available in the path, and so Flutter cannot find it.